# Removing nodes divisible by 2 gives a SIGSEGV error

Tags: c, debugging, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a function which removes all nodes in a linked list whose values are divisible by the chosen number.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//add_beg - adds node at beginning
//add_end - adds node at the end
//add_at - adds node at the specified index
//remove_divisible_by - removes node if divisible by num (SIGSEGV)
//print_nodes - prints nodes


struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node node_t;

node_t *head = NULL;

void remove_divisible_by(int num)
{
    node_t *temporary = head;

    while(temporary != NULL) //ERROR IS PROBABLY HERE
    {
        if(temporary->link->value % num == 0) 
        {
            temporary->link = temporary->link->link;
        }

        temporary = temporary->link;

    }
}

void add_at(int index, int value)
{
    node_t *new_node_ptr = calloc(sizeof(node_t),1);

    new_node_ptr->value = value;

    node_t *temporary = head;

    while(index>1)
    {
        temporary = temporary->link;
        index--;
    }

    new_node_ptr->link = temporary->link;
    temporary->link = new_node_ptr;

}

void add_beg(int value)
{
    node_t *new_node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new_node_ptr->value = value;
    new_node_ptr->link = head;

    head = new_node_ptr;
}

void add_end(int value)
{

    node_t *new_node_ptr;

    new_node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new_node_ptr->value = value;
    new_node_ptr->link = NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node_ptr;
        return;
    }

    node_t *temporary;
    temporary = head;

    while(temporary->link != NULL) temporary = temporary->link;

    temporary->link = new_node_ptr;


}

void print_nodes(node_t *head)
{
    node_t *temporary;
    temporary = head;
    while(temporary != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temporary->value);
        temporary = temporary->link;
    }
}

int main()
{
    add_end(2);
    add_end(3);
    add_end(5);

    add_beg(1);

    add_at(3,4);

    remove_divisible_by(2);

    print_nodes(head);

    return 0;
}
```

The bug seems to be in the function `remove_divisible_by`

What happens:
If I want to remove the nodes divisible by 2, I get a SIGSEGV error.
If I want to remove the last node (in this case, numbers divisible by 5) in the list, it works.

On the other hand, if I write `while(temporary->link != NULL)` in the `remove_divisible_by` function, removing the nodes divisible by the number 2 actually works, but then I get a SIGSEGV error if I want to remove the last node (nodes divisible by 5)

My question is, why exactly does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: The `while` loop should check that both `temporary` and `temporary->link` are not NULL.

Comment: `while(temporary != NULL || temporary->link != NULL)` doesn't seem to be working

Edit: it works, I'm just dumb. It's `&&`, not `||`

Comment: Try `&&` instead

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. If you have time, could you explain what's the issue?

Comment: I think if you put a 2 at the beginning of the list, you'll find that you still have another bug to fix.

Comment: The first element could be done manually, I suppose. I was working with `temporary->link` instead of `temporary` cause I couldn't think of a way to link the node that's behind `temporary` to the node that's in front of `temporary`. (Since I can't go backwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
        if (temporary->link->value % num == 0)
        {
            temporary->link = temporary->link->link;
        }
```

... you are not examining the current node (`temporary`) but the next node (`temporary->link`), which may not exist (i.e. `temporary->link` is `NULL`) hence your segfault.

Always work with the current node inside your loop. The only time you have to use `temporary->link` is at the end of your loop, in order to switch to the next node (`temporary = temporary->link` as you did).

Comment: I was working with the next node cause that was my way of solving this problem:

If I work with the node I'm currently at, then I can't think of a way to link the past node to the next node (thereby removing the current node from the list). I can't go backwards

Comment: You can still store the previous node in a variable similar to `temporary`. In any case, you won't escape the check that the node exists (i.e. is not NULL). Besides, as mentioned by @user3386109, the fact that you are not processing the current node makes you miss the first node.

Comment: Thanks. That's the best solution, simply creating another variable.

Comment: On last thing: you are supposed to `free()` the nodes you delete because they were `calloc()`'ed. Else you will get what is called a memory leak.